# Declare multiple value variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to write an IN statement when setting the `RECEIPTIDS` variable, so that I can pass multiple values in that format into my query. I have tried the following:

```
DECLARE @RECEIPTIDS VARCHAR(2000)
SET @RECEIPTIDS = ('R00013','R00028')
```

However, I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need extra single qoutes.

```
    create table MyTable
    (
       ID varchar(50) 
    )
    insert into MyTable values('R00013')
    insert into MyTable values('R00028')
    insert into MyTable values('R00015')

    DECLARE @RECEIPTIDS VARCHAR(2000)
    SET @RECEIPTIDS = ('''R00013'',''R00028''')
    DECLARE @QUERY VARCHAR(100)

    SET @QUERY='SELECT * 
    from MyTable 
    where ID IN ('+@RECEIPTIDS+')'
    EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Edited: Use it with Dynamic query.

Comment: that does not answer the question, because this results in a variable holding a `single value` whereas OP asked about `multiple values`  in one variable, you would need to include a use of a function to split that string into a sequence of values to provide a complete example

Comment: @DrCopyPaste updated the answer , OP can use it with dynamic query

Comment: Nice one! Here's also a fiddle if anyone wants to try that out online. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c6627/1

Answer (score 5):

You need [table variable](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/27/sql-server-storing-variable-values-in-temporary-array-or-temporary-list/) or [temp table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2008/03/30/sql-server-table-variable-vs-local-temporary-table.aspx).

```
DECLARE @RECEIPTIDS TABLE(val VARCHAR(100))
Insert into @RECEIPTIDS values ('R00013'), ('R00028')
```

You can use it in IN as

```
where field IN (Select val from @RECEIPTIDS)
```

Comment: I get the following: `Must declare the scalar variable`

Comment: I am able to execute it successfully. I suspect some typos somewhere.

Comment: No i cannot execute it. I wrapped square brackets around the variable but still no luck

Comment: Try to first execute above example. If it does not execute then i suspect SQL server version issue

Answer (score 3):

Use temporary array or temporary List

```
DECLARE @ListofIDs TABLE(IDs VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @ListofIDs VALUES('a'),('10'),('20'),('c'),('30'),('d')
SELECT IDs FROM @ListofIDs;
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Must declare the scalar variable`

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me either but this did:

```
DECLARE @RECEIPTIDS TABLE(val VARCHAR(100))
Insert into @RECEIPTIDS values ('R00013'), ('R00028')

where field IN (Select val from @RECEIPTIDS)
```