# sql to check string contains with where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

in Sql server

I have a following string

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max);
set @str = "Hello how are you doing today,Its Monday and 5 waiting days";

DECLARE @srch nvarchar(max);
set @srch = " how,doing,monday,waiting";
```

Now i want to check whether str contains any of string (comma separated string) of srch

I want it in only sql server

is there possibilites to write some query with in clause

like

```
select from @str where _____  in (select * from CommaSplit(@srch)
```

where CommaSplit function rerturns rows of @srch comma separted value

I dont want to use cursor or any loop concept as the @srch value can be very long

Thanks

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584865/declare-multiple-value-variable-in-sql/19585026?noredirect=1#comment29068637_19585026

Comment: You're better off using a loop concept if @srch is long than trying to use in.
Using loop you can make a function which splits your string into a table result and then join into that result. It gives you much better flexibility and likely also performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use same function to get first string  in rows

```
select string from CommaSplit(@srch,'') where string  in (select * from CommaSplit(@srch)
```

Comment: This will works only if the strings in the @srch variable are also separated by coma. Otherwise the result will not be correct...

Comment: Thanks it worked, as i have control over srch string, but i think you have mistaken that at first occurance of @srch should be str

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following common table expressions query to split your string into parts. `cte` will contain one record per phrase in `@srch`. In my example below, I show where in `@str` each of the search phrase is located. It returns 0 if it cannot locate a search phrase.

Note 1: it won't show the location twice if your search phrase is duplicated - you would need another CTE for that.

Note 2: I have to add comma at the end of `@srch` to make my CTE work. You can do that inside the CTE if you prefer not to change the search string.

```
DECLARE @str nvarchar(max);
set @str = 'Hello how are you doing today,Its Monday and 5 waiting days';

DECLARE @srch nvarchar(max);
set @srch = 'how,doing,monday,waiting';

set @srch = @srch + ','

-- first split the text into 1 character per row
;with cte
as
(
    select substring(@srch, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @srch, 1) - 1) as Phrase, CHARINDEX(',', @srch, 1) as Idx

    union all

    select substring(@srch, cte.Idx + 1, CHARINDEX(',', @srch, cte.Idx + 1) - cte.Idx - 1) as Phrase, CHARINDEX(',', @srch, cte.Idx + 1) as Idx
    from cte
    where cte.Idx < CHARINDEX(',', @srch, cte.Idx + 1)
)

select charindex(cte.Phrase, @str, 1) from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the IN clause is what you need. Instead of this you can use the LIKE construction as following:

```
 if (select count(*) from CommaSplit(@srch) where @str like '%' + val + '%') > 0
      select 'true'
 else
      select 'false'
```

In this case you will receive `'true'` when at least 1 result of `CommaSplit` function exists in the `@str` text. But in this case you also will receive a `'true'` value when the result of `CommaSplit` function is a part of the word in the `@str` string.

If you need more accurate solution, this can be achieved by the following way: you need to split the `@str` into the words (also replacing punctuation by spaces beforehand). And, after this, intersect of `CommaSplit (@srch)` and `SpaceSplit(@str)` will be the answer on the question. Among this, you also will be able to check which words are matching between two strings.

The overhead of this method is to create function `SpaceSplit` which is copy of `CommaSplit` but with another separator. Or the function `CommaSplit` can be modified to receive a separator as parameter.